# How to rename deployment descriptor ie. web.xml?

Tags: tomcat, web.xml

Why should a deployment descriptor file be always web.xml ? In case if I change to some other name, will it work fine ? I need to understand the whole things how it works?

Comment: Presumably it detects it by looking for a file called `web.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

That's just what the Java Servlet standard has decreed that the deployment descriptor should be called.

Is there a good reason to want to change the name?

Comment: No reason, but want to know how tomcat detects deployment descriptor. Does it have any configuration stating that the deployment descriptor file is web.xml

Comment: I don't know if that is configurable. Could well be hard-coded. But yes, Tomcat looks for a WEB-INF/web.xml and treats it in a special way.